# Target all selectors where attr is equal to value from Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, cookies, each

I need to fadeOut all li's where id is equal to the values, how can I do that? Atm it affects all li's, not just the ones with the matching id's.

```
var cookie = jQuery.cookie('wishlist_cookie');
var parse = jQuery.parseJSON(cookie);
jQuery.each(parse['itemlist'], function (index, value) {
    var id = value['wishlist_item_id'];
    jQuery('li').attr('id', id).fadeOut();
});
```

**parse['itemlist']** returns

```
[Object wishlist_item_id: "227482" __proto__: Object ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

err...what about `jQuery('#'+id).fadeOut()`

alternatively (should be faster):

```
var cookie = jQuery.cookie('wishlist_cookie'),
    parse = jQuery.parseJSON(cookie),
    ids = jQuery.map(parse['itemlist'], function (index, value) {
        return '#' + value['wishlist_item_id'];
    });

jQuery(ids.join(',')).fadeOut();
```